# Why using zero timing (#0)in verilog is not good practice?

Tags: verilog

Why using **zero** timing is not good.
I cant find details about that any what problem will arise if w use that method.

Comment: It *might* be useful if you provide some context. If your going to use 0 timing why use timing in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

Designers are often tempted to use #0 to avoid race conditions between two procedural blocks. A #0 in a procedural block forces that block to stop and be rescheduled after all other blocks. The problem happens when you have a multiple blocks that all want to execute last. Who should win?

This itself can become a new race condition and its resolution could vary from run to run and from simulator to simulator. In short, multiple threads using #0 delays can cause non-deterministic execution behavior.

Besides, it makes your code hard to read and also non-synthesizable. SystemVerilog has provided new constructs for avoiding #0 in a more predictable and readable way. Here is [one example](http://www.deepchip.com/items/0466-07.html) (See 7.2 Event trigger race conditions).

Note that there are cases other than the classics usage of #0 in SystemVerilog that you may actually need to use #0. For example, differed assertions.